# My iPod Nano seems to have been lost in post! How do I contact Apple?

Tags: contacts

I posted my iPod Nano to Apple two weeks ago, under their replacement service, but the "check repair status" says that they still haven't received it. Does anyone know a number or an email address I can use to chase this up?

Comment: I should add that I am in the UK.

Comment: How did you send it? You should have sent it with a tracked service, which you will need to take up with the service provider you used. I would contact them if Apple say they cannot do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any web site in the UK  has to provide contact information. [Apple](http://www.apple.com/uk/contact/) has a comprehensive one.

> Sales Support
>   Check the status of a current Apple Online Store order. To make changes to an existing order, contact Apple Store Customer Service at 0845 600 1683 (low rate). Lines are open Monday-Friday 08:00-21:00, and Saturday-Sunday 09:00-20:00.

Comment: A note to others who have sent in their iPods. Apple told me that they have a huge backlog in processing these due to a response to the recall far far higher than they were expecting. They have now hired additional staff to work thought the backlog, and should be able to process the iPods soon...